# In app purchase getting receipt and save it

Tags: ios, ios6, in-app-purchase, subscription, receipt-validation

My app has a server side receipt validation for auto renewable subscription.
Particularly at each restart the app needs to check if the receipt is still valid.
On iOS7 it seems pretty easy, with just those lines of codes i can get the receipt:

```
// Load the receipt from the app bundle.
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
if (!receipt) { /* No local receipt -- handle the error. */ }

/* ... Send the receipt data to your server ... */
```

With iOS6 it seems to fallback to the `transactionReceipt`. To get I have 2 options:

- Save it after the purchase
- Asking it again as a restore purchase

Here are the problems, In the first case I guess the receipt would be valid only for the subscription period and which is a correct place to save it?. 
In the second case restoring the purchase will trigger the App Store popup message, pretty boring asking it at each startup.
Can someone enlight me on the correct path?